# How should I set up a new local user for IIS to run under?

Tags: security, windows-server-2008-r2, asp.net, iis-7.5

I'm interested in setting up a full-blown local user to run my ASP.NET web sites under in IIS 7.5 (Windows Server 2008 R2).

*(The long and boring rationale has to do with System.IO.Packaging's use of Isolated Storage. Running the offending code under another AppDomain using MarshalByRef or serialization isn't really an option.)*

I've always used the user defaults for IIS (AppPoolIdentity, Network Service, IUSR, etc.), so I'm looking for advice in how to *properly* set up a regular user for IIS.

What pitfalls should I look out for, especially around permissions and security?

Answer (score 1):

In IIS7.5, When you create a separate Application Pool for your website a separate User is created automatically. It means different websites have completely different users, so I'm wondering why you may need to assign a regular user? I don't think if it's possible because of many security risks. A regular user has lots of permissions in system and as a result, attacker can do many system calls through your website.

Comment: The question already states why this is needed. This isn't a hosting farm. I was able to easily switch my app pool to the new user, I'm just looking to be sure the default user permissions aren't a problem. Obviously, this user doesn't have remote login privileges or access to unnecessary files.

Comment: I think they don't recommend this because by the way it gives more power to hackers (at least regular user can read HDD) and if there is a security issue in IIS or Windows, hacker can do system calls through port 80, although user doesn't have remote login privilege.